# JQuery scrollTop not smooth on ios devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

as part of a bigger system I have a div which acts like a heading. JQuery is used to create a "fixed" effect where "scrollTop" is used to keep the header at the top. Overall this works, however on ios devices the scroll is not smooth at all and quite jumpy.

The code which does the scroll looks similar to this:

```
$('.mydiv').css('top', $passedVar.scrollTop());
```

I know that this can be resolved using "position: fixed;" but if it's possible to get a JQuery solution it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use jQuery's `.css()` to add `position: fixed; top: 0;` instead. That might help, but if you're calling this on-scroll, it will still be jumpy. It's not smooth because you're probably calling this every time you scroll 1px (a bazillion times). That's probably not great. What is your reasoning for not doing this with CSS?

Comment: You may find this helpful: http://tinyurl.com/pk2d4nv